# How to push a new view controller to the navigationcontroller present at that time in tabbarcontroller?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I had a tabbarcontroller application in which i am created that like this

```
UITabBarcontroller (UIWindow's rootViewController)
    ->UINavigationController (first tab)
       -->UIViewController
    ->UINavigationController (second tab) 
       -->UIViewController
```

in the navigation bar i had a button in which i am pushing another view controller to the self .navigation controller.But now i want the same action from the other navigation controller also. so i need to push to the navigation controller which is the top view controller.I need to replace the `[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:NO];` with in a way that whichever is the navigation controller present there in the tabbar controller we need to add to that.Can any body help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well how simpler than holding a refference to the UInavigationController that is currently visible (you should hold that refference from the UITabBarController delegate `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`)

So you add in your AppDelegate a variable:

```
UINavigationController *navController;
```

then :

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (viewController.navigationController)
        navController = viewController.navigationController;
}
```

Now, you do the push this way:

```
if (navController)
   [navController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:NO];
```

Comment: I think viewController from tabBarController:didSelectViewController should be already NavigationController

Comment: Yes, correct, but the viewController.navigationController should return it correctly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So at first you need have access to `TabBarController`. I think you can get it somewhere in `AppDelegate`.

then you can just call:

```
UIViewController *ctrl = myTabBarCtrl.selectedViewController;
[ctrl.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:NO];
```

Comment: This has the problem that if the user has selected a Tab that is a simple UIViewController it will crash, as the `myTabBarCtrl.selectedViewController` will return a `UIViewController` and not a `UINavigationController` object

Comment: Sure. It's based on TC's navigation design. But I've updated code to be more stable.